# check the divisibility by 13 of a binary number

Tags: c++, binary, bit-shift, bit, bitset

how to check if a binary number is divisible 13 if the user inputs the digits from the most significant to the least significant?

the number of bits can be very large,so there is no point converting it into decimal and then checking its divisibility.

i have approached it in the conventional way.
nuber of bits range upto 10^5, so it is giving overflow while converting it into decimal.

how to approach this?
example:

110010000100100
it is div by 13

111111111111111
it is not divisible by 13

Comment: @EricHotinger i am not aware of it.please elaborate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an O(N) algorithm:

Traverse the bits from left to right.  Each additional position is equivalent to multiplying the current value by 2, and then adding either 0 or 1.  This is also true in modulo-13 arithmetic.  When you get to the last bit, see if the final value is equal to 0.  If it is, then the original number was divisible by 13.

Comment: Two quick precisions: first, an algorithm cannot be faster than O(N) if reading all bits/digits is required; second, this algorithm is O(1) in space.

Comment: actually i got it now.i was unaware of bitshifting before but now it is crystal clear